# Any good ftp client for a 9'' netbook?

Tags: ftp, netbook

I currently run FileZilla  client but it's too large to fit the screen correctly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's your current and maximum screen resolution?

Comment: I feel the pain. I run FileZilla on a 10" netbook. Great question.

Comment: Which OS are you running on your netbook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can hide a lot of FileZilla's interface parts in the View menu, even the directory trees. Go into Settings > Interface and move the message log next to the transfer queue, if you haven't hidden them both or you want to see them. Select a theme with 16x16 icons.

You can end up with a UI with very little wasted screen space.

Comment: I actually might try that, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) has a nice configurable interface, still useful at small screen sizes. It might be to your liking.

Comment: Yes, WinSCP in Explorer view mode will work.

Comment: WinSCP also supports SCP (obviously) and SFTP, as does FileZilla, so you can use these more secure (and sometimes more efficient) protocols too.

Answer (score 3):

Command Line would be the Smallest Method.

However if you have Firefox, and have it tweaked to run on a small screen i Highly Recommend. FireFtp Addon for Firefox.

http://fireftp.mozdev.org/

Comment: FireFTP is really nice

Answer (score 2):

Command line FTP.  Simple, clean, works.  The only client I will troubleshoot problems with when a customer complains one of my FTP sites isn't working.

Command line ncFTP if you want something more powerful.

(Although I suspect you are asking for a GUI, not a command line client.)

Comment: ncftp was going to be my suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an advanced file-manager? Something like Directory Opus, or Midnight Commander will also do FTP. Some of these have long histories and are also designed to be largely keyboard driven, which I find nice on my netbook.

Comment: +1 I always install Dopus on my systems, it's worth every penny...

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Mozilla Firefox, the FireFTP addon is really nice. Very compact, definitely made for smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lightweight ftp client called [ThorFtp](http://www.caerustech.com/ThorFtp.php). It's efficient so it should work well when resources are scarce.

[image]

> ThorFtp is an FTP client geared toward developers. While lacking fancy
>   graphics and special effects, this tool is maximized toward
>   functionality and performance to allow a busy developer to be
>   efficient and precise. ThorFtp is a purely Java based product, thus
>   utilizing the Java technology reliability and security in your every
>   day work.
>
> Please click "Download ThorFtp" link in the left panel to download the
>   software package. ThorFtp is a freeware, thus it is allowed to be used
>   free of charge for all personal and commercial purposes.
>
> Once downloaded, the package can be unzipped and placed in any local
>   directory. Please note that this software requires local machine to be
>   Java enabled to execute. Once the package is unzipped, the application
>   can simply be started by double clicking ThorFtp.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

ncftp from a normal terminal like gnome-terminal would work nicely.

You did not mentioned what os you use, so I assume some Linux dist...

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in tools might work:

- Windows: Windows Explorer (**NOT** IE)
- Linux: Nautilus or Conquerer

Though, using Windows Explorer can be an ugly pain, because the forgets most of the time the username and password.